# Migrating RAID 0 to SSD

Tags: ssd, migration, raid-0

First let me say I'm a newbie when it comes to cloning/migrating etc.

I bought a computer that is setup in a raid0, 2 500 GB drives.

I have 116GB of that space used, and I want to migrate to a single 256GB SSD drive.

I have EaseUS todo backup, an edition that allows me to do a universal restore.

Would I be just cloning and checking the "optimize for SSD" box and clone my drive to an SSD, or do I need to backup to dissimilar hardware and do it that way.

Or am I completely off?

I can't just start fresh so please don't recommend that as an option.  I have too many programs/serials/settings etc involved so my only option is migrating, or just not upgrading.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Ethan

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense. Try it and see what happens. Don't erase the old drives until you know it works.

Comment: you can also try using Acronis True Image, it clones your full drive as an image that you can then choose to restore in whatever way you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

RAID 0 is a [stripe](http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them). You will need both disks. Make a backup of them and test the backup.

Remove both drives (this is so they do not get changed and you can replace them if things did not work as planned.

Make sure the BIOS/UEFI si set to AHCI. (Best for an SSD, might be set to IRRT if you previously used Intel fake RAID).

Add the SSD. Do whatever EaseUS needs and restore to the SSD (I never used EaseUS so my excuses if this is a bit general).

Make sure things work and are set for an SSD (Mainly, automatic defragmentation is off).

If it does, add one of the old drives. You can use it to store data on (e.g put movies on that drive, while leaving the OS and often used programs on the SDD).

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple to answer this question. YES, you can have a :Raid 0" on two or more mechanical drives and migrate it to a single SSD. I use "Samsung drives on my PC's and their "Migration Tool". I with never a problem move the "Raid 0" to the SSD. It is a piece of cake and works great. Download the Migration tool to the existing mechanical raid 0 drive and then instruct it to migrate to the SSD. DONE DEAL...